# Git commit gone from VS 2019: what happened?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, git-commit

I recently updated VS 2019 to 16.7.1.

Now I wanted to commit changes to my local repo and to the github repo.

But alas: the commit is gone from the solution pull-down. I only have a git option (with "undo changes", "history" and "Blame"): like "read only".

I have a lot of red marks beside files, so they still have to be committed. But I can't. The option is not there.

Installed Github extension is GitHub.VisualStudio   2.11.102.28613

Sound familiar? What can I do?

Comment: with 16.7 MS added the new git ui: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/exciting-new-updates-to-the-git-experience-in-visual-studio/ disable/enable it again

Comment: Had the same problem, I believe this is fixed in a later release of 16.7.